# Can I Add Parameter for Template Type of Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

Now I have a template class as base class, declaration as below

```
template<class TKey, class TValue>
class BaseKeyValueData
{ ... }
```

Also I declara a element class which targets to replace TKey and TValue in above base class

```
class BasicElement
{
    BasicElement() = default;
    BasicElement (const std::string& input) { ... }
}
```

Then I want to create a derive class from BaseKeyValueData, and also replace TKey with BasicElement, but still leave TValue as template argument for derive class. The declaration as below

```
template <class T>
class DeriveValueClass() : BaseKeyValueData<BasicElement, T>
{
    DeriveValueClass() : BaseKeyValueData<BasicElement, T>() {}
    ...
}
```

Above code I had implemented and it works. But according new requirement, I want to use a string parameter to initial the BasicElement instance. In above DeriveValueClass class, its default constructor uses BasicElement's default constructor (without parameter). So How can I use a parameter to initial BasicElement in DeriveValueClass constructor. The dummy code as below:

```
DeriveValueClass() : BaseKeyValueData<BasicElement(<parameterForBasicElement>), T>() {}
```

Above code is illegal in C++. How can I implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is unclear. The only consturctor that matters is `BaseKeyValueData<TKey, Tvalue>`, since this is what `DeriveValueClass` inherits from. It doesn't inherit from `BasicElement`, therefore it does not need to construct it. This is obviously not the real code that you're trying to compile, but fake code, using fake class name. Unfortunately, the only thing that you'll get to questions about fake code is fake answers. You need to post real code, that generates real compilation errors, if you want a real answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, actually your commit triggers me idea. I find the answer in it. Really thanks! I really confuse between type declaration and object initialization. In my question, I list the code of type declaration of template class. Actually, I initial the type in my cpp file, so that's the place I should consider to transfer the parameter of constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question, it really confuses the type declaration and instance initialization. For DeriveValueClass declaration, it just declares the type, not related its constructor. So if want to create the type instance, it should explicit call the type's constructor. In my cpp code, I have explicit create type instance, such as:

```
boost::make_shared<TKey>()
```

This is the right place  for considering to use different constructor to initial the instance.